# java.net.InetAddress won't work on GAE free-tier

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I have this code that I need to run with GAE,

```
public class RootServerResource extends ServerResource {
  @Get("json")
  public String represent() {
    String client = getRequest().getClientInfo().getAddress();
    InetAddress addr = null;
      try {
          addr = InetAddress.getByName(client);
      } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
    String domain = addr.getHostName();
    return "hello, world (from the cloud!), your client domain is: " + domain;
  }
}
```

But it throws:

> Caused by:
>   com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException: The
>   Socket API will be enabled for this application once billing has been
>   enabled in the admin console.

Is there a work-around on this issue, is there any way to get domain from IP with GAE? Some way that Socket API would not be invoked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain lookups need outbound sockets, so you need to have Socket API accessible by your app. As the docs say [Sockets API is only available for paid apps](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/sockets/#limitations_and_restrictions).

One way around it would be to instead use reverse-domain-lookup service that has a HTTP interface such as this one: http://www.statdns.com/api/ (see Getting Reverse PTR Records at end of page).

Comment: Yeah, this makes senses.